# Error when inserting into Database in Python

Tags: python-3.6

What is wrong with the code to produce this error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

I am using XAMPP Localhost Database and mysql.connector Package in Python. My Code for Inserting:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
username = input()
sql = "INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `username`) VALUES (NULL, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, username)
db.commit()
print("success")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
cursor.execute(sql, username)
```

try this

```
cursor.execute(sql, [username])
```

execute expects a list/(list of tuples) as the second parameter. You can have a look at the [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/mysqlclient/latest/mysqlclient.pdf) if you need more details.